# Generating random numbers in c++ language

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>

int random[1000];

using namespace std;

char* getDateTime(time_t  &x);
short getGeneratedNumber(time_t &dateTime);

int main()
{
    time_t now = 0;
    char* timeString;
    int i = 0;
    timeString = getDateTime(now);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++) {
        random[j] = getGeneratedNumber(now);
        cout << random[j] << "  ";
    }
}

char* getDateTime(time_t  &x) {

    // current date/time based on current system
    x = time(0); // updates the value of the variable now

    // convert now to string form
    char* dt = ctime(&x);

    return dt;
}

short getGeneratedNumber(time_t &x) {
    return x % 1000;
}
```

I want to generate 1000 random numbers only using this method, but it generates the same number. What did I do wrong? Also I want to store those 1000 values as well.

Comment: Not that you should be doing this in the first place, but ask yourself how many times you call `getDateTime` during the course of your program. In fact, count them. It won't take long. Then, stop doing this with `time` and start using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Its what's for dinner for non-crypto-strength random numbers in modern C++ programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your loop is wrong (remember that in C++, as opposed to MATLAB, indexing starts at 0):

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
```

Second, you read the time exactly *once* by a *single* call to `getDateTime` before the loop transpires, then generate the same number based on the read time, repeatedly calculating the unchanging `x` modulo 1000, and naturally receiving the same repeated result. Passing `x` by-reference to `getGeneratedNumber` is currently pointless, as you're never changing it.

Third, replace `int random[1000];` with some other name, like `int rnd[1000];`, as the symbol `random` may conflict with the library function `random`.

Fourth: If possible, use [the "modern" way of generating random numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).